# Why is $_SESSION reset if i open url with url.openStream?

Tags: java, php, session, session-variables

I'm using the following code to read content from a URL:

```
public static String getPageContent(URL url) throws IOException {

   InputStream in = url.openStream();
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

   byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

   while (true) {
      int byteRead = in.read(buffer);
      if (byteRead == -1) {
         break;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < byteRead; i++) {
         sb.append((char) buffer[i]);
      }
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Then i call it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] as) {
   try {
      URL u = new URL("http", "localhost", "/sessiontest.php");
      System.out.println(getPageContent(u));
      System.err.println(getPageContent(u));
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

My sessiontest.php contains:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['asd'])) {
   echo "set";
   unset($_SESSION['asd']);
} else {
   echo "not set";
   $_SESSION["asd"]="asdasdajklhlòjkl";
}
?>
```

This code prints out `set` when `$_SESSION['asd']` is set, and then `not set` if it is not set

When calling my URL multiple times, it should output "not set" the first time, and then "set" the second time, "not set" the third time, etc.

The problem is that with my code i'm calling two times the same page and i always receive "not set" as output for sessiontest.php, while if i access my page two times from any browser i see "not set" and then "set".

It seems that php handles all my connections as different sessions, why?

Comment: http://www.jroller.com/mipsJava/entry/urls_and_cookies

Answer (score 0):

Print the value of session_id() to see if the generated id is same across all the requests or not. It should be same for one session. For some reason if its not same check the permission on the directory where sessions are stored. Also you could try manually setting the value using session_id($id);